# CAML <RowLimit></RowLimit>

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I am working with Nintex workflow and want to get the maximum number for a list entry, to do this I am Querying a list using CAML, sorting it by the Approval Limit and want to just choose the top value using the

```
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
```

Here is my full Query:

```
<Query>
  <Lists>
   <List ID="{87697670-EB15-472F-B45E-23C23974FE23}" />
  </Lists>
  <ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name="Approval_x0020_Limit" />
   <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
   </ViewFields>
   <Where>
   <And>
   <Contains>
    <FieldRef Name="Business_x0020_Area"  />
    <Value Type="Choice">{WorkflowVariable:Var_BusinessArea}</Value>
  </Contains>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Commercial_x0020_Approval"  />
    <Value Type="Boolean">{WorkflowVariable:Flag_Commercial}</Value>
  </Eq>
</And>
 </Where>
 <OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name="Approval_x0020_Limit" Ascending="false" />
   </OrderBy>
   </Query>
```

However this query still returns the 3 values that are in the list (and I would only like it to return the highest value)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You query element is incorrect - ViewFields and RowLimit elements should be placed in View element not Query element. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms471093%28v=office.12%29.aspx
Does Nintex allow you to provide View or only Query?

Comment: Nintex only allows Query. However there is an option to limit the number of rows "out of the box" with Nintex - so problem solved! Thanks